# python + how to verify which python wheel or rpm installed that equivalent to import XXXX

Tags: python, linux, pip, rpm, python-wheel

in some python script we can see the import of some python modules as

```
import yum
import rpm
.
.
.
```

can we find exactly the rpm or wheel that actually installed the yum or the rpm ?

for example by `pip list | grep yum`

I not sure that I get the wheel that represent the "`yum import`"

and from `rpm -qa | grep yum` I get long list

so how to know the specific package that installed ?  that related to `import yum` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ strace python3 -c 'import rpm' 2>&1 |grep open
....
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rpm/__pycache__/transaction.cpython-311.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled", O_RDONLY) = 3
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/rpm/__pycache__/transaction.cpython-311.pyc
python3-rpm-4.18.1-3.fc38.x86_64
```

If the rpm tells you

```
file XXXX is not owned by any package
```

then the file was not installed from rpm. So it likely comes from `pip install`.